# How to send a parameter to a page by GuzzleHttpClient in Laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I have an address that I want to send to.
But the result of the page I want information from is forbiden-403.
How do I fix this problem?
exp:

```
    use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

$client = new Client();

```
    $request = $client->get("https://1xbit1.com/datalinelive/topchamps",[
        [
            'live' => $request->live,
            'return_data' => $request->return_data,
            'main' => $request->main,
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

403 means that you're not authorized. Basically it means that you're *authenticated* ("logged in") but you're not allowed to take the action you're trying to do. However if you're sure that you're authenticated and authorized, read along:

The [Guzzle Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=json#query-string-parameters) are pretty comprehensive and you should be able to find what you're looking for over there. As you're making a GET request, I suppose you want to send your parameters as a query string:

```php
    $request = $client->get("https://1xbit1.com/datalinelive/topchamps",[
 //     \/ \/ \/ send your parameters as a query string
        'query' => [
            'live' => $request->live,
            'return_data' => $request->return_data,
            'main' => $request->main,
        ]
    ]);
```

On the other hand, if you need to store some data, chances are that you want to to a POST request. In this example you'll be posting JSON data. The `json` option automatically sets the appropriate headers:

```php
    $request = $client->post("https://1xbit1.com/datalinelive/topchamps",[
 //     \/ \/ \/ send your parameters as a query string
        'json' => [
            'live' => $request->live,
            'return_data' => $request->return_data,
            'main' => $request->main,
        ]
    ]);
```

You can substitute `json` for `body` if you want to send form-encoded data.